# Starring all my liked items in Google Reader

Tags: google-reader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to mass-star items in Google Reader?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/is-there-a-way-to-mass-star-items-in-google-reader)

I've been "liking" items in Google Reader to keep them around, but that's been changed. You can now +1 them (and publish that in your G+ timeline) - or you can star them.

I would like to keep my old liked items together with my newly liked items. And the only way I see for that to happen is to star all my old liked items.

There's an export option under Reader Settings for old liked items. It's a JSON file, containing the URL to the page (among other things).

How can I automate starring all those items?